# I'm trying to create a vpc access connector with terraform, but the subnet is in a shared network

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create a vpc access connector with terraform, but the subnet is in a shared network of the host project network-nonprd and I can't declare it in the code

```
# resource "google_vpc_access_connector" "connector" {
  region  = "southamerica-east1"
  name    = "vpcserverlessconnector"
  subnet {
    name = "projects/network-nonprd/global/subnetworks/subnet-sls-nonprd"
  }
  min_instances = 2
  max_instances = 10
  machine_type = "e2-micro"
}
```

Error

```
│ Error: Error creating Connector: googleapi: Error 400: Please provide a properly formatted subnet name.
│
│   with google_vpc_access_connector.connector,
│   on terrafile.tf line 1, in resource "google_vpc_access_connector" "connector":
│    1: resource "google_vpc_access_connector" "connector" {
```

can someone help me?

I tried

```
name = "projects/network-nonprd/global/subnetworks/subnet-sls-nonprd"
```

Comment: Try with just `subnet-sls-nonprd`.

Comment: hello
putting subnet-sls-nonprd 

Error: Error waiting to create Connector: Error waiting for Creating Connector: Error code 3, message: Operation failed: VPC Access did not have permission to resolve the subnet or the provided subnet does not exist

I'm creating with terraform with a service account. I added the service account in both projects as an editor to test and it gave an error

Comment: Hello, that way it worked

subnet {

name = "subnet-sls-nonprd"

project_id = "network-nonprd"

}

Thank you for your help